# Array expected errors after subtle code changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project where I need to combine several tabs into one and they have different amount of columns on each tabs sometimes with different column names. I asked on here and got a code that works. The first code list below is the one that works and it will save the three tabs I need as CSV files. Which I can then manually load into SQL just fine. Then I tried to modify the code to instead of saving them as CSV files to load it into SQL. The first step I took towards that was to modify it so that instead of saving them as CSV files it would just remove all tabs but the three I needed then I was going to add the load into SQL section. However I started getting Object required errors on the line "If cbSht Is Nothing Then" this is a section of the code that I did not make any changes to and I can not figure out why it is throwing this error. The second code listed below is the code with the error.

Edit1: Thanks to the comments of FunThomas and Taller the Object Required error was fixed by defining the variables properly. Now I am getting and array expected error. I have updated the code below. The new error is happening on this line " For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)". The code is highlighting "LBound(arrData," again this is not a section of the code that was change.

First Code(Working Code)

```
Option Explicit


Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vKey, oDic, arrData, rngData, cell As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, iC As Long, iRes As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, cbSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Const CB_SHT = "CombinedData"
    
    
    'remove unneeded sheets
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Sheets(Array("About", "Overview_Total", "Overview_Casino", "Overview_Sports", "Overview_iGaming", "Statewide")).Delete

    
    'Fix the RI opened data
    Sheets("RI").Columns("C:C").Replace What:="1993", Replacement:=""
    
    'All Caps headers
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        oSht.Activate
        With Rows(1)
        .Value = Evaluate("SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address(External:=True) & "),)), "","", ""|"" ),"" "",""_"")")
        End With
    Next oSht
    
    
    'Move Distributed and Sports betting to new workbooks
    
    Sheets("Distributed").Columns("F:J").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
    Sheets("Distributed").Columns("K:Z").Delete

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Distributed").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\filepath\Distributed.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
  
    
    Sheets("Distributed").Delete
    
    Sheets("Betting by Sport").Columns("E:AJ").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Betting by Sport").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\filepath\Sports_betting.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
  
    Sheets("Betting by Sport").Delete
    
    
    ' Create CombinedData sheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cbSht = Sheets(CB_SHT)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If cbSht Is Nothing Then
        Set cbSht = Sheets.Add
        cbSht.Name = CB_SHT
    Else
        cbSht.Cells.Clear
    End If
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    iR = 2
    ' loop through worksheet
    
    
    
    For Each oSht In Worksheets
        If oSht.Name <> CB_SHT Then
            LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 1 Then
                LastCol = oSht.Cells(1, oSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1", oSht.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
                arrData = rngData.Value ' load data into an array
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    If Not oDic.exists(arrData(1, j)) Then
                        oDic(arrData(1, j)) = oDic.Count + 1
                    End If
                Next
                ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) - 1, 1 To oDic.Count)
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    iC = oDic(arrData(1, j))
                    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
                        arrRes(i - 1, iC) = arrData(i, j)
                    Next
                Next
                ' Write ouput to CombinedData sheet
                cbSht.Cells(iR, 1).Resize(UBound(arrRes), oDic.Count).Value = arrRes
                iR = iR + UBound(arrRes)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Populate headers
    ReDim arrRes(0, 1 To oDic.Count)
    i = 0
    For Each vKey In oDic.Keys
        i = i + 1
        arrRes(0, i) = vKey
    Next
    cbSht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, oDic.Count).Value = arrRes
    
    
    
    
    
    ' Copy out the final sheet
    Sheets("CombinedData").Columns("I:GN").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
    LastCol = Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(1, Sheets("CombinedData").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(Sheets("CombinedData").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rngData = Sheets("CombinedData").Range("I2", Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    

    rngData.Replace What:="false", Replacement:=""

    rngData.Replace What:="N/A", Replacement:=""
    rngData.Replace What:="NA", Replacement:=""
    rngData.Replace What:="#VALUE!", Replacement:=""
    
    Set rngData = Sheets("CombinedData").Range("A1", Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    
    rngData.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=""
    
   ' Sheets("CombinedData").Columns("C:C").Replace What:="Bet365", Replacement:=""
    
 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CombinedData").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\filepath\Gaming_Revenue.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
End Sub
```

Second Code (Broken Code)

```
Option Explicit



Sub Demo_testing()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, ColCnt As Long, arrRes As Long, iR As Long, iC As Long, iRes As Long
    Dim vKey As Range, oDic As Range, arrData As Range, rngData As Range, cell As Range
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, cbSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, ignore1 As Worksheet, ignore2 As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As Variant, sheetsToKeep As Variant
    Dim found As Boolean
    Const CB_SHT = "CombinedData"
    
    
    'remove unneeded sheets
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Sheets(Array("About", "Overview_Total", "Overview_Casino", "Overview_Sports", "Overview_iGaming", "Statewide")).Delete

    
    'Fix the RI opened data
    Sheets("RI").Columns("C:C").Replace What:="1993", Replacement:=""
    
    'All Caps headers
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        oSht.Activate
        With Rows(1)
        .Value = Evaluate("SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address(External:=True) & "),)), "","", ""|"" ),"" "",""_"")")
        End With
    Next oSht
    
    
    'Rename betting tab
    Sheets("Betting by Sport").Name = "Sports_Betting"
    
    'Reformat Distributed and Sports betting to new workbooks
    
    Sheets("Distributed").Columns("F:J").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
    Sheets("Distributed").Columns("K:Z").Delete
    
    Sheets("Sports_Betting").Columns("E:AJ").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    

    
    
    ' Create Gaming_Revenue sheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cbSht = Sheets(CB_SHT)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If cbSht Is Nothing Then
        Set cbSht = Sheets.Add
        cbSht.Name = CB_SHT
    Else
        cbSht.Cells.Clear
    End If
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    iR = 2
    ' loop through worksheet
    
    Set ignore1 = Sheets("Distributed")
    Set ignore2 = Sheets("Sports_Betting")
    
    For Each oSht In Worksheets
        If oSht.Name <> CB_SHT And oSht.Name <> ignore1 And oSht.Name <> ignore2 Then
            LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 1 Then
                LastCol = oSht.Cells(1, oSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1", oSht.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
                arrData = rngData.Value ' load data into an array
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    If Not oDic.exists(arrData(1, j)) Then
                        oDic(arrData(1, j)) = oDic.Count + 1
                    End If
                Next
                ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) - 1, 1 To oDic.Count)
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    iC = oDic(arrData(1, j))
                    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
                        arrRes(i - 1, iC) = arrData(i, j)
                    Next
                Next
                ' Write ouput to Gaming_Revenue sheet
                cbSht.Cells(iR, 1).Resize(UBound(arrRes), oDic.Count).Value = arrRes
                iR = iR + UBound(arrRes)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Populate headers
    ReDim arrRes(0, 1 To oDic.Count)
    i = 0
    For Each vKey In oDic.Keys
        i = i + 1
        arrRes(0, i) = vKey
    Next
    cbSht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, oDic.Count).Value = arrRes
    
    
    
    
    
    ' Copy out the final sheet
    Sheets("CombinedData").Columns("I:GN").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
    LastCol = Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(1, Sheets("CombinedData").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(Sheets("CombinedData").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rngData = Sheets("CombinedData").Range("I2", Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    

    rngData.Replace What:="false", Replacement:=""

    rngData.Replace What:="N/A", Replacement:=""
    rngData.Replace What:="NA", Replacement:=""
    rngData.Replace What:="#VALUE!", Replacement:=""
    
    Set rngData = Sheets("CombinedData").Range("A1", Sheets("CombinedData").Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    
    rngData.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=""
    
    Sheets("CombinedData").Columns("C:C").Replace What:="Bet365", Replacement:=""
    
 

    


    ' Array of sheet names to keep
    sheetsToKeep = Array("CombinedData", "Sports_Betting", "Distributed")

    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        found = False

        ' Check if the current sheet is in the array
        For Each sheetName In sheetsToKeep
            If ws.Name = sheetName Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next sheetName

        ' Delete the sheet if it's not in the array
        If Not found Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does Gaming_Revenue exist? That's different than the first sample.

Comment: Gaming_Revenue is just a renaming of the CombinedData. In both cases that tab does not exist but it should instead create that tab. I will try it going back to the CombinedData name just to be sure though.

Comment: In VBA, if you want to have multiple variable declarations on one line, you need to specify the type explicitly for every variable, eg `Dim oSht As Worksheet, cbSht as Worksheet, ws As Worksheet`. In your case, you declare `oSht`, `cbSht`, `ws`, and `ignore1` as Variant, and only `ignore2` is of type Worksheet. A variant can *hold* an object, but it can hold anything else, and if it is not initialized, it's value is `empty`. You can't compare `empty` with `Nothing`, therefore your runtime error.

Comment: `Dim cbSht as Worksheet` , then `If cbSht Is Nothing Then` works well.

Comment: @FunThomas I did not realize i had to define each one i thought i could list them all thank you

Comment: That fixed the problem of the object required but now I am getting a different problem I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why do you have `arrData As Range`? Should be a `Variant`. `oDic As Range` looks wrong too, should be `As Object`. `Dim vKey As Range` looks off too.

Comment: Those three as range is what was given too me on a previous question I had asked and that part works just fine in the first code.

Comment: I just realized that @taller is helping here and they helped me with the first part of this project. It has just grown from what I had first asked.